# Why JPA query left join on codition not working?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, left-join, jpql

I'm using Hibernate as JPA implementation and have two tables: `User` and `Agency`.

Each `Agency` can have many users. A `User` can have one or zero `Agency`

`User`

```
public class User {
  @Id
  private String userId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(nullable=true)
  @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  private Agency agency;
}
```

`Agency`

```
public class Agency {
  @Id
  private String agencyCd;

  private String delFlg; //0 means in use

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="agency")       
  private List<User> userList;
}
```

In the repository, query is

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.agency a on a.delFlg='0')
```

My problem is, left join on codition(a.delFlg='0') is not working.

Agencies with delFlg is 1 are all included in the results.

How can I find user with left joined agencies whose `delFlg` is 0?

Comment: Maybe `@Query("SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN Agency a on a.delFlg='0'")` or `@Query("SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u Where u.agency.delFlg='0'")`

Comment: It is because you are using `left join` instead of `inner join`. Left join will filter results but won't affect rows of output `User`. To make sure you get `User` with `delFlg = 0`, you need to use `inner join`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your case is explicitly described in the JPA Specification 4.2 Section 4.4.5.2

> An outer join without a specified join condition has an implicit join condition over the foreign key relationship corresponding to the *join_association_path_expression*. It would typically be mapped to a SQL outer join with an ON condition on the foreign key relationship as in the queries below:
> Java Persistence query language:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN s.products p GROUP BY s.name
> ```
>
> SQL:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p.id)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Products p
> ON s.id = p.supplierId GROUP By s.name
> ```
>
> An outer join with an explicit ON condition would cause an additional specified join condition to be added to the generated SQL:
> Java Persistence query language:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN s.products p
> ON p.status = 'inStock' GROUP BY s.name
> ```
>
> SQL:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p.id)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Products p
> ON s.id = p.supplierId AND p.status = 'inStock' GROUP BY s.name
> ```
>
> Note that the result of this query will be different from that of the following query:
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN s.products p WHERE p.status = 'inStock'
> GROUP BY s.name
> The result of the latter query will exclude suppliers who have no products in stock whereas the former query will include them.

So your query should probably be:

```sql
SELECT u 
FROM User u 
LEFT JOIN u.agency a 
WHERE a IS NULL 
OR a.delFlg='0'
```

Comment: very nice examples which clearify SQL <> JPQL in relation of JOIN. Thank you.